# What does odd/even iteration mean?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-guo-hall-thinning-algorithm/

Was looking at Guo-Hall algorithm but I don't understand the part where it says

```
 * @param  iter  0=even, 1=odd
```

Comment: Well... This line is a comment in the code and tells to pass 0 for evern and 1 for odd in parameter iter.

Comment: Removed F# tag as this has nothing to do with F#.

Comment: Yeah but what does odd/even iteration mean in this context? Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

It means parameter `iter` controls current process based on whether it is an odd iteration or an even iteration.

```
void thinningGuoHallIteration(cv::Mat& im, int iter) {...}
```

Given 3×3 window showing the 8-neighborhood of pixel `p(i,j)`,

[image]

It will do differently for odd iterations and even iterations:

[image]

You can further learn how it is called:

```
do {
    thinningGuoHallIteration(im, 0);
    thinningGuoHallIteration(im, 1);
    cv::absdiff(im, prev, diff);
    im.copyTo(prev);
} 
while (cv::countNonZero(diff) > 0);
```

You can see that it just run it one even iteration followed by one odd iteration.

Check out [here](http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-guo-hall-thinning-algorithm/) for more info.

Comment: So is it the same as saying run iteration A then iteration B then back to A etc. . .?

Comment: @Dakaa Yes, until `countNonZero(diff) <= 0`.

Comment: What does the condition while (cv::countNonZero(diff) > 0); mean? Sorry, I'm not familiar with OpenCV, trying to translate this code to other language.

Comment: @Dakaa Simply because they are called within a `do-while` with condition `while (cv::countNonZero(diff) > 0);` :P